# Unable to display sensitivity/specificity with confusionMatrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I have a following table that I want to analyze using `confusionMatrix`:

```
value<-cbind(c(rnorm(100,500,90),rnorm(100,800,120)))
genotype<-cbind(c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))
df<-cbind(value,genotype)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df)<-c("value","genotype")
df$value<-as.numeric(as.character(df$value))
table(value>600,genotype)
```

i want to analyze the output for sensitivities and specificities with the `confusionMatrix` but it does not work:

```
confusionMatrix(table(value>600,genotype))
```

Any thoughts if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work". Do you get an error message? If so, please post it. Also, `confusionMatrix` is from the `caret` package, so add `library(caret)` to the beginning of your code. In general, when posting a question on SO, you should include all information necessary to reproduce your problem. That makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: @eipi10 good point, sorry for missing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your table, you'll see that it's not in the right format. The row and column labels should be the same, but they aren't in this case.

```
tab = table(value>600,genotype)

tab

       genotype
         A  B
  FALSE 83  6
  TRUE  17 94
```

When we run `confusionMatrix`, we therefore get an error due to the different row and column labels (that's what the error message is telling you):

```
confusionMatrix(tab)
```

> ```
> Error in !all.equal(rownames(data), colnames(data)) : 
>   invalid argument type
> ```

Normally, to create the confusion matrix, you should have a column of predicted labels and a column of reference labels (the true values), so I'm not sure the table you've created is meaningful as a confusion matrix. In any case, just to show the right formatting for the table, let's change the row labels to be the same as the column labels. Then the function will work:

```
dimnames(tab)[[1]] = c("A","B")

tab

genotype
   A  B
A 83  6
B 17 94

confusionMatrix(tab)
```

> ```
> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
>
>    genotype
>      A  B
>   A 83  6
>   B 17 94
>
>                Accuracy : 0.885           
>                  95% CI : (0.8325, 0.9257)
>     No Information Rate : 0.5             
>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2e-16         
>
>                   Kappa : 0.77            
>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.03706         
>
>             Sensitivity : 0.8300          
>             Specificity : 0.9400          
>          Pos Pred Value : 0.9326          
>          Neg Pred Value : 0.8468          
>              Prevalence : 0.5000          
>          Detection Rate : 0.4150          
>    Detection Prevalence : 0.4450          
>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.8850          
>
>        'Positive' Class : A
> ```